# Is it true that acting can affect one's behavior?

Tags: social-psychology

Is it true that acting can affect one's behaviour?

For example, if someone plays a protagonist, can this affect them to be a good person? Is there any solid evidence for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is true. [Mot *et al*. (1994)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092656684710208) published scientific research about it. Also there are a lot of actors that claim they feel that their personality has changed since they played a role.

Also a similair practice can be used for insecure people. If they act confident it has been proven that after some time, they feel more confident as well.

---

**Edit:**

Since I'm new to stackexchange I did not know how much detail is desired. Therefore, let me expand upon my original comment.

The article states the following hypotheses:

> (1) the actor chosen to play a given character would have personality characteristics similar to that of his or her corresponding character

---

> (2) the actor′s self-perceived personality profile would become more similar to the character′s during the rehearsal and production period.

Later on the article states that:

> Support emerged for the second hypothesis, but not for the first. Observations regarding these findings and suggestions for future explorations are given.

The article expands upon this, but I can't access the paper, because it's pay-walled.

**Reference:**

- [Hannah M. T., Domino G., Hanson R. Hannah R. (September 1994) Acting and Personality Change: The Measurement of Change in Self-Perceived Personality Characteristics during the Actors Character Development Process, *Journal of Research in Personality*, 28(3):277-286](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092656684710208)

Comment: I wonder if this study can also scientifically back the claim "fake it til you make it"

Comment: @EdmundReed To break your question down further, the only difference between 'fake it till you make it' and this article is that in the article people act like a fictional character while with 'fake it till you make it' it applies to  a non-fictional character. If I were to research it, my hypothesis would be that the effects would be more apparent by 'faking' since I think that people draw the line more between themselves and a fictional character than themselves and a 'fake' version of themselves.

Comment: really interesting reply, I agree completely - thanks.